# Combining Attributes for a Conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% @user.chores.each do |chore| %>
<li><%= chore.name %></li>
<% end %>


<% @user.chorelists.each do |chorelist| %>
<li><%= chorelist.day %></li>
<% end %>
```

Hola, friends.

My app has three models: User, Chore, and Chorelist (which is a 'joined' resource for User and Chore).

Both of these blocks work, but how can I write, say, a conditional statement that will give me all of that user's chores for a specified day? (The days are saved in the Chorelist model as strings.)

If you need anymore more code from the app, just let me know. And thank you!

Comment: Try `@user.chorelists.select{|i| i.date == DATE}.each do |chorelist|`

Comment: It should be done in the controller instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be great to know what fields do your models have. Meanwhile, I think that you want something like this:

```
date = Date.today        
@user.chores.joins(:chorelist)
            .references(:chorelist)
            .where(chorelists: {day: date})
```

And this should be in your controller, yeah, per commenter's suggestion.